# mat-label animation error inside mat-form-field | Angular Material 15

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm working in an new Angular 15 project with Material 15.
I've faced this issue with inputs inside form fields:
[image]

There is no errors in the console.
I checked all the imports inside the module:

```
imports: [
BrowserModule,
AppRoutingModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule,
MatTabsModule,
MatCardModule,
MatFormFieldModule,
MatInputModule,
MatButtonModule
],
```

Here is the HTML of the input:

```
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-full" floatLabel="always">
      <mat-label>Firmenname</mat-label>
      <input matInput placeholder="z. B. company GmbH">
    </mat-form-field>
```

Did I miss something here?